# How is it that a child process that calls exec() right after forking wouldn't need a separate copy of the parent's address space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am reading "Linux Kernel Development, Second Edition" by Robert Love. (Yes, it's a bit outdated). I understand from Chapter 3: Process Management that in COW (copy-on-write), the parent and child processes share the parent's address space until one of the processes writes to the address space. This is to prevent the unnecessary duplication of the parent's address space when it is not even being written to.

But then, it mentions that if the child process calls `exec()` right after `fork()`, the parent's address space and pages DON'T need to be copied and given to the child as a separate copy. That's where I'm lost.

According to the manual, *"the exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image."* The manual doesn't say anything about `exec()` creating a new address space for the new process image. So if the child process is sharing address space with its parent, wouldn't this mean that `exec()` would load an executable image into the parent's address space (which is shared with the child)?

Since that means the parent's address space would be overwritten, I don't understand how a child process that executes `exec()` after `fork()` WOULDN'T need a separate copy of its parent's address space to write to. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-on-Write mechanism implies, that **none modification in child process will affect on parent**.

Calling `exec` by the child is not an exception: it changes address space only for child, not for the parent.

Comment: Indeed. exec() will replace the memory mapping entirely, but only for the calling process. Only non-memory-mapped resources survives: file-descriptors (without the CLOEXEC flag), current-directory, UID, GID and friends, permissions, etc.

Comment: So does this mean that the child gets a separate address space, that doesn't contain the memory-mapped resources of the parent, but only the non-memory-mapped resources (meaning not as much copying is done)?

Comment: Yes, it does. Documentation for `fork()` describes, which non-memory-mapped resources are shared with child. In its turn, documentation for `exec()`  describes which resources remains in the new process image.

Comment: Alright, that clears things up tremendously. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can even read on vfork() which doesn't have copy on write mechanism. It shares the address space of the parent process and parent process is suspected untill child process exists. It is interesting and makes things much more clearer.